# How to populate a ListView from ArrayList<CustomClass>?

Tags: android, android-listview, populate, rss-reader

I'm writing an android RSS feed reader.

when my program read the feeds at the end return me an ArrayList

Item is my class:

```
public class Item implements Serializable {

    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String link;

    public Item() {
        setTitle(null);
        setDescription(null);
        setLink(null);
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

}
```

Now how can I populate a custom ListView that has 3 TextView in it for `Title`, `description` and `link`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to write a custom ListView. You should use a personalized layout and custom adapter.

**First,** write a layout to define how each row should look. Here's a basic example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/link"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:padding="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

(Save it as `list_item.xml` in your `res/layout` folder.)
**Next,** I recommend that you create a custom adapter to efficiently display your layout:

```
public class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Item> objects;

    public ItemAdapter(Context context, List<Item> objects) {
        this.objects = objects;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            // Do the same for description and link
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        Item item = objects.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());
        // Same for description and link
        return convertView;
    }

    // Override the other required methods for BaseAdapter

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView description;
        TextView link;
    }
}
```

To learn more about custom adapter's, ViewHolders, and efficiency please watch Android's Romain Guy [talk on this subject](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html).

Hope that helps!

Comment: I like your answer but I think OP didn't even try to read any tutorial on listviews and adapters.

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov I have that feeling too. But someone else dumped a useless answer here first and many of the search engine tutorials are slow (a pet-peeve of mine), so I took 10 minutes to whip this up.  Also my layout is primitive and there's more work to be done in general, this leaves the OP with plenty more to learn!

Comment: @nikita you know i tried to find a good tutorial for 2 days but all i found had something wrong in it.

Comment: this : context.getSystemService made me crazy because in one tutorial they write it like this: getSystemService

Comment: Next time you struggle like that, visit the [Android Developer's page](http://developer.android.com/) and try searching the documentation for the method (in this case `getSystemService`). This may will help.

Comment: i use this code : Items itms = rss.parse(Accessor.fileReader("rss.jsp"));
  lv.setAdapter(new ItemAdapter(this, itms)); for set my listView adapter but it doesnt work!!!!

Comment: The phrase "but it doesnt work!!!!" is not very helpful. Does it crash? (If so post your LogCat in the question, that way I can see why it crashed). Is it just blank? (If so, `itms` is empty.)

Comment: Sam there is no Error or even warning in my log but it is just blank. but i test the itms and it was not empty because I can see its elements in TextViews for example

Comment: Hmm, did you add valid information to the other base adapter functions? For example if `getCount()` returns `0`, then obviously nothing will be displayed. It must return `objects.size()`. Also try adding `Log.v("Item", item.getTitle() + ": " + item.getDescription());` in the `getView()` method after the line `Item item = objects.get(position);`. Let me know what you see.

Comment: Sam its running now problem was that object.size() really thanks brother. by the way can i have your mail address or skyp id? because im truly new in android an d i need a friend just like u man

Comment: I'm glad it is working, please click the checkmark to mark this as correct. I am on Stack Overflow almost every day, you can notify me by adding `@Sam` to a comment here with a link to your new question and I'll take a look. Cheers!